# Referring to a multiproperty object inside another object

Tags: javascript

We store instances of `flyweight` object into the `flyweights` object. Then, to refer to a `flyweight`  we use this syntax `flyweights[project + priority + user + completed]`. Where is this `+` syntax coming from and does it mean:  this property needs to match `+` this property needs to match, etc.?

```
    function Flyweight(project, priority, user, completed) {
    this.priority = priority;
    this.project = project;
    this.user = user;
    this.completed = completed;
};

var FlyweightFactory = function () {
    var flyweights = {};

    var get = function (project, priority, user, completed) {
        if (!flyweights[project + priority + user + completed]) {
            flyweights[project + priority + user + completed] =
                new Flyweight(project, priority, user, completed);
        }
        return flyweights[project + priority + user + completed];
    };

    }
    return{
        get: get

    }
}()
```

Comment: Its concatenating a string to lookup your object. `flyweights` is an object - `project + priority + user + completed` forms the key

Answer (score 1):

Using the `+` operator on object will automatically call for every one its `toString()` method and concatenate those strings. That means `project + priority + user + completed` is a string (unless all variables are numbers, then the `+` is interpreted as the normal addition).

With `foo['bar']` you are accessing the property `'bar'` within the object `foo` (-for further readings, check: [mdn docs link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)).

So all in all `flyweights[project + priority + user + completed]` will get you what is stored inside `flyweights` under the key(-string) `project + priority + user + completed`.